# Loop through cells in range using cell references for the Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a cells in range using this piece of code. But it throws error in last statement given here

> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

What is the alternative/solution to it. Thanks for your replies.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastcolTTR))
Rng.Select

For Each ct In TTRfile.Rng.Cells
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Post full code. What is `TTRfile`?

Comment: Maybe it should be `Worksheets("TTRfile")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how `TTRfile` or `ct` are declared, but I know `Rng` is a `Range` which means `TTRfile.Rng.Cells` is a problem, if not ***the*** problem.

If `ct` is a variant or a range object then you can use `For Each` and a syntactically correct way of creating the loop is:

```
For Each ct In Rng.Cells
```

However, if `ct` is numerical, as could be the case with `ct = Rng.Cells.Count` then you cannot use  `For Each`and must use an incrementing/decrimenting index variable:

```
For i = 1 to ct
```

Also, you're implicitly using the `ActiveWorksheet` when you set `Rng`, you should get into the habit of explicitly qualifying the worksheet. If `TTRfile` is a worksheet then

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastcolTTR))
```

Would look like this:

```
TTRfile.Range(TTRfile.Cells(1, 1), TTRfile.Cells(1, lastcolTTR))
```

Or this:

```
With TTRfile
    .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1, lastcolTTR))
End With
```

Speaking of `lastcolTTR`, how is that declared?  It can become a  problem if it doesn't evaluate to a number.  For example, if it is a variant then it becomes possible for it to hold a range and you will get an error if that range contains more than one cell.  Also, be sure you catch any condition that would cause `lastcolTTR` to be less than 1 because `Cells(1,0)` will generate an out of range error.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply and the valuable points. I understood where I was wrong. Corrected it now. Thanks again! 

It was simple. This is what worked for me For Each ct In Rng.Cells